# Question about Spring transaction propagation

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a question about Spring *transaction propagation*.

Suppose I use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` to annotate a method `m1()`. When execution logic enters `m1()`, if there is already a transaction, `m1()` will use that one. When after `m1()`, what about the transaction? It will end or still remain open? (if I call `m1()` in another method, and after the invocation there is still other things to do).

In summary, I want to know **when exiting** an annotated method, the transaction ends or still remains open?

Great thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Propagation.REQUIRED` (documented [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED)) will create a new transaction (if none exists for the current thread), or will join an existing transaction (if one exists).

When the method exits, then the transaction will be completed (if entering the method caused a transaction to be created), or will leave the transaction open (if a transaction already existed when the method was entered). In other, words, it's symmetrical, and will leave the thread's transactional state in the same state it was before the method was entered.

Comment: Hi staffman, what about other propagation level with regard to my question?

Comment: @Yousui: The various propagation levels, and their effects, are documented in the link I posted.

Comment: Thank you staffman, after reading your answer carefully and do some testing, I have understood the spring transaction propagation policy. Great thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yousui Could you post the scenarios you tested out? I'm facing difficulties understanding the finer intricacies between REQUIRED vs REQUIRES_NEW. My transaction boundaries are defined separately, with each operation called from an external flow, so I should essentially be seeing the operations sequentially, but I'm still running into problems.