# Get the data which is inserted using @Transactional in the same transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mybatis

I am inserting the data in one method(has `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.Required)`) but in the other method(has `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.Required)`) if I try to get the same data it is giving null.

Both methods are wrote in service layer with `@Transactional (rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

How to get the data which is inserted in the same transaction.
Something like :-

```
 @Service
    public class Service{
        @Transactional
        public void method(){
            mapper.insert();        //insert to DB(Using Mapper interface)
            ServiceLayer.method2()
        }
    }

@Service
public void ServiceLayer{

    @Transactional
    public static void method2(){
        result  = mapper.select() //Select inserted data - returning null
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer...after removing @transactional from `ServiceLayer.method2()` it's worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In order to persist the changes made to the current session you can invoke `entityManager.flush();`

Comment: How?? i am using spring-mybatis.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worked, but it's not a solution.
In your case, your `Transaction` from `Service.method()` created a transaction that is not committed yet. That's why you can't fetch it.