# Spring Data Repository @Query - Update and return modified entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

let's assume we have a Spring Data repository interface with a custom method...

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE MyEntity SET deletedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?1")
void markAsSoftDeleted(long id);
```

This method simply sets the deletedAt field of the entity, ok. Is there any way to allow this method to return an updated version of the `MyEntity`?

Obviously...

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE MyEntity SET deletedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?1")
MyEntity markAsSoftDeleted(long id);
```

...does not work, since...

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type!

Does anyon know another way to easily allow that, except of course the obvious "add a service layer between repository and caller for such things"...

Comment: Just to be clear, you’re not happy with the standard method of getting then updating and saving the entity if it exists? JPA tends to prefer the implementation to be able to be aware of any modifications to entities.

Comment: In this case, since we do not yet have a service layer, I wanted to keep it simple and solve the "problem" in the Repository with a simple query, which leads of course to some implications, thus the question. With a service layer, of course one would simply "manually" load the entity and update it.

Comment: share the repository class at least the basic declaration of it

Answer (score 6):

Set **clearAutomatically** attribute on @Modifying annotation.That will clear all the non-flushed values from EntityManager.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE MyEntity SET deletedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?1")
void markAsSoftDeleted(long id);
```

To flush your changes before committing the update latest spring-data-jpa has another attribute on @ModifyingAttribute. But I think its still in 2.1.M1 release.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true, flushAutomatically = true)
```

Please check corresponding jira bug request: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-806

Another approach can be you can implement custom repostiory Implementation and return your updated entity after done with the query execution.

Reference : [Spring data jpa custom repository implemenation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

Comment: This is not supported by Spring -> "Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type"

Comment: @Sangam Belose , were you able to achieve this?

Comment: this way in Spring throws Exception: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do that:

**The JPA idiomatic way** to do this is to load the entities first, then changing them using Java code.

Doing this in a transaction will flush the changes to the database.

**If you insist on doing a batch update** you need to mark the entities as part of the update. Maybe with a timestamp, maybe the update itself already marks them. And then you reload them using a select statement that uses the marker set during the update.

Note that you have to ensure that the entities don't exist yet in your `EntityManager`, otherwise you will keep the old state there. This is the purpose of `@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)` recommended by other answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)
```

Its works for me.

Answer (score -3):

It will never return `void` or your class type, add return type `int` or `Integer` like below,

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE MyEntity SET deletedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?1")
Integer markAsSoftDeleted(long id);
```

Comment: a small change, the docs say the return type would be void or int/integer denotes the number of records updated.