# How to update an entity with a condition(where clause) and get the updated entity in method response in spring data jpa

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am working on concurrent update handling stuff, my scenario is- an employee can be marked inactive from UI, but if once marked inactive, it should not be allowed to marked inactive again. I want to achieve it by making the db update call with a condition update entity where status=active. I need the updated entity in return.

How to update an entity with a condition(where clause) and get the updated entity in method response in spring data jpa

```
employeRepository.save(employee); // is it possible to do something like this with a condition at the same time update method returns updated entity.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working against the grain of JPA here.

I suggest you do it the JPA way:

1. load the entity
2. If the `status` property is not `inactive` set it to `active`.
3. When ever the transaction ends this will be written to the database.

If you insist on using an update statement

You can use the following process:

1. If the entity is part of the current session:

   1. flush all changes to the database.
   2. evict the entity from the session.
2. perform an update either using SQL or JPQL with a where clause like this: `... WHERE id = :id and status <> 'inactive'`
3. use the id to load the entity again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JPQL**.

```
uery query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "UPDATE employee SET status = \"inactive\"" +
                    "WHERE status=\"active\"");
    query.executeUpdate();
```

or just spring data

```
@Modifying
@Query("update employee u status = `inactive` where status=`active` and ...")
void disableUsers(...);
```

however, to deal with concurrent queries a good way could be **Optimistic locking** and `@Version` annotation.

Comment: I want the update method to return updated entity as well.

Comment: For your case, optimistic locking and `@Version` annotation may be good enough and then You can use  employeRepository.save(employee).

Comment: is it possible to achieve something like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690671/spring-data-repository-query-update-and-return-modified-entity

Comment: it is impossible, SQL update returns the only number of updated rows.  "Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type"

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional.

@Transactional //try to add this annotation
@Modifying
@Query("update employee u status = `inactive` where status=`active` and ...")
```

void disableUsers(...);