# Java Spring @Transactional prevent concurrency

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

How do I prevent a concurrency in Spring transactional?

The situation is two requests in parallel to the method below:

```
@Transactional
public save() {
    Optional<Example> result = repository.findById(1);
    if(!result.isPresent()) {
        Example exemple = new Exemple();
        exemple.setParam1(1);
        exemple.setParam2(1);
        exemple.setParam3(1);
        exemple.setParam4(1);
        exemple.setParam5(1);
        exemple.setParam6(1);
        exemple.setParam7(1);
        exemple.setParam8(1);
        repository.save(exemple);
    }
}
```

So, for exemple, the second request passes through the "ifPresent" verification before the first request ends and commit. Causing unexpected behavior and saving the object twice.

Do I need to use the @EnableTransactionManagement? Do I need to use some value in @Transactional?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct relationship between your problem and the `@Transactional` behavior. The problem you encountered was the classic issue unsynchronized methods called from a few threads, while `@Transactional` ensures that all changes in the database occur simultaneously after they have been committed.

The simplest solution is to make the method that **calls** this `save` (=a wrapper method [Because of the AOP nature, it must be in another class otherwise the `@Transactional` won't take affect]) `synchronized`. For more information, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41767861/504807).