# How many jdbc connection can be used in one spring transaction?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-transactions

Suppose there are following components which are configured all together:

- jdbc connection pool
- DataSource
- Dao

Suppose there is method which is marked with `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and contains several `dao` methods calls. Do all these dao methods use the same connection during transaction or not?

Answer (score 0):

If they all have the same Datasource, and you are only using Spring to create and manage your transactions, then yes.

Reason: because of isolation and propagation behaviour see:  [Spring @Transactional - isolation, propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490852/spring-transactional-isolation-propagation), there will only be one transaction which all the DAO methods use. And there is only one connection used per a transaction in JDBC.

Comment: Could you provide any proof?

Comment: The connection itself is what is providing the transaction behaviour: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html