# Spring transactions - isolation and propagation understanding

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am exploring spring transactions and after going through the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED) and the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490852/spring-transactional-isolation-propagation) i still have few questions. If I have a parent method with *Propogation.REQUIRED* which is calling 3 methods with  *Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW* as follows:

```
//@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Contact saveContactInSteps(Contact contact, String newFirstName, String newLastName, Date bDate) throws Exception {
    contact.setFirstName(newFirstName);
    try {
        updateContactFirstName(contact);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Contact first name could not be saved !!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

    contact.setLastName(newLastName);
    try {
        updateContactLastName(contact);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Contact Last name could not be saved !!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

    contact.setBirthDate(bDate);
    updateContactBday(contact);

    return contact;
}

public Contact saveById(Contact contact) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(contact);
    LOG.info("Contact " + contact + " saved successfully");
    return contact;
}

//@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Contact updateContactFirstName(Contact contact) throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Cannot update first name");
    //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(contact);
    //LOG.info("Contact First name saved successfully");
    //return contact;
}

//@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Contact updateContactLastName(Contact contact) throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Cannot update last name");
    //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(contact);
    //LOG.info("Contact " + contact + " saved successfully");
    //return contact;
}

//@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Contact updateContactBday(Contact contact) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(contact);
    LOG.info("Contact Birth Date saved successfully");
    return contact;
}
```

Whenever i process the parent method i.e. `saveContactInSteps`, even the last name is getting updated in database. I am not sure how that is happening. If i throw the exception from first child method nothing gets updated. Is it because of the fact that i am setting the attributes i.e. names and birthdate in the parent method ? Even if i am setting the attributes in the parent method, i am not letting the parent method complete as well. Does the `isolation` level play any part here ? I believe it's for concurrent transactions ? Is there something i am missing ?

**EDIT 1**:

After going through the article i did realize what i was missing. I needed AOP proxies in place which i have added as follows:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut
        expression="execution(* org.pack.spring.transactions.ContactService.*(..))"
        id="updateOperation" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="updateOperation" advice-ref="saveUpdateAdvice" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="saveUpdateAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" isolation="DEFAULT" rollback-for="Exception"/>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" rollback-for="Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Log output is as follows:

```
01:23:57.535 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:57.550 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
01:23:57.552 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'saveUpdateAdvice'
01:23:57.552 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'saveUpdateAdvice'
01:23:57.552 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'saveUpdateAdvice' to allow for resolving potential circular references
01:23:57.553 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
01:23:57.553 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#56ac5c80'
01:23:57.553 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
01:23:57.553 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
01:23:57.557 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.i.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [update*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-Exception]
01:23:57.557 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.i.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [save*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-Exception]
01:23:57.557 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
01:23:57.557 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
01:23:57.557 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
01:23:57.557 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
01:23:57.558 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#56ac5c80'
01:23:57.558 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'saveUpdateAdvice'
01:23:57.558 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'saveUpdateAdvice'
01:23:57.568 [main] DEBUG o.s.a.a.a.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'springTxContactService' with 0 common interceptors and 3 specific interceptors
01:23:57.575 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Creating CGLIB proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService@598260a6]
01:23:57.654 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.save(org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact)
01:23:57.654 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.saveContactInSteps' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:57.655 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.saveContactInSteps(org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Date) throws java.lang.Exception
01:23:57.655 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.findAll' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
01:23:57.656 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public java.util.List org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.findAll()
01:23:57.656 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.findById' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
01:23:57.656 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.findById(java.lang.Long)
01:23:57.657 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.saveById' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:57.657 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.saveById(org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact)
01:23:57.657 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.updateContactFirstName' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:57.657 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.updateContactFirstName(org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact) throws java.lang.Exception
01:23:57.658 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.updateContactLastName' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:57.658 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.updateContactLastName(org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact) throws java.lang.Exception
01:23:57.658 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.updateContactBday' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:57.658 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.updateContactBday(org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact)
01:23:57.659 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.setSessionFactory' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:57.660 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public void org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)
01:23:57.661 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'ContactService.getSessionFactory' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:57.661 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.getSessionFactory()
01:23:57.661 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Found 'equals' method: public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)
01:23:57.662 [main] DEBUG o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()
01:23:57.698 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
01:23:57.698 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
01:23:57.698 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'saveUpdateAdvice'
01:23:57.698 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sessionFactory'
01:23:57.698 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'hibernateProperties'
01:23:57.698 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
01:23:57.698 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
01:23:57.699 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory'
01:23:57.699 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
01:23:57.746 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@21d1b321]
01:23:57.747 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
01:23:57.750 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source
01:23:57.752 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springTxContactService'
01:23:57.755 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
01:23:57.762 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.findById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
01:23:57.962 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for Hibernate transaction
01:23:57.964 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
01:23:57.965 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springorm]
01:23:57.977 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Setting JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2a685eba] read-only
01:23:57.983 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2a685eba]
Hibernate: select distinct contact0_.ID as ID1_0_0_, contacttel1_.ID as ID1_2_1_, hobby3_.HOBBY_ID as HOBBY_ID1_3_2_, contact0_.BIRTH_DATE as BIRTH_DA2_0_0_, contact0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NA3_0_0_, contact0_.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAM4_0_0_, contact0_.VERSION as VERSION5_0_0_, contacttel1_.CONTACT_ID as CONTACT_5_2_1_, contacttel1_.TEL_NUMBER as TEL_NUMB2_2_1_, contacttel1_.TEL_TYPE as TEL_TYPE3_2_1_, contacttel1_.VERSION as VERSION4_2_1_, contacttel1_.CONTACT_ID as CONTACT_5_2_0__, contacttel1_.ID as ID1_2_0__, hobbies2_.CONTACT_ID as CONTACT_2_1_1__, hobbies2_.HOBBY_ID as HOBBY_ID1_1_1__ from contact contact0_ left outer join contact_tel_detail contacttel1_ on contact0_.ID=contacttel1_.CONTACT_ID left outer join contact_hobby_detail hobbies2_ on contact0_.ID=hobbies2_.CONTACT_ID left outer join hobby hobby3_ on hobbies2_.HOBBY_ID=hobby3_.HOBBY_ID where contact0_.ID=?
01:23:58.099 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
01:23:58.101 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact#6], EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactTelDetail#6], EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactTelDetail#7]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact.contactTelDetails#6], CollectionKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact.hobbies#6]]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
01:23:58.103 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2a685eba]
01:23:58.103 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact#6], EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactTelDetail#6], EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactTelDetail#7]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact.contactTelDetails#6], CollectionKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact.hobbies#6]]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
01:23:58.117 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactService.saveContactInSteps]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
01:23:58.117 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for Hibernate transaction
01:23:58.117 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
01:23:58.117 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springorm]
01:23:58.127 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1daf3b44]
01:23:58.127 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for Hibernate transaction
01:23:58.127 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
01:23:58.127 [main] ERROR o.p.c.s.t.h.home.ContactService - Contact First name could not be saved !!
01:23:58.127 [main] ERROR o.p.c.s.t.h.home.ContactService - Contact Last name could not be saved !!
01:23:58.137 [main] INFO  o.p.c.s.t.h.home.ContactService - Contact Birth Date saved successfully
01:23:58.138 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
01:23:58.138 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact#6], EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactTelDetail#6], EntityKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.ContactTelDetail#7]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact.contactTelDetails#6], CollectionKey[org.pack.ch9.spring.transactions.hibernate.home.Contact.hobbies#6]]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
```

**Note** - I have removed the `@Transactional` annotations from the methods as i am relying on proxy to achieve the same.

From the logs, it seems that the proxies are getting created but again as pointed out in the comment, will the 3 methods invoked from `saveContactInSteps` not have a transaction against them as mentioned in the documentation :

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code, i.e. @PostConstruct

Is there a way to get around this ? Is `AspectJ` the only solution ?

Comment: Calling a method from the same bean won't start another transaction. Transaction hndling is proxy-based. You need to go through a proxy to have Spring start a new transaction. This is explained in the Spring documentation. BTW, don't read the Spring 3.x documentation. The current version of Spring is 5.c. 3.x is obsolete. Also a non-runtime exception doesn't cause a rollback. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction

Comment: Ok. After re-reading the docs, it looks like using @Transactional by default uses mode = proxy. So, going by annotation based approach, how can i achieve what i want to achieve ?

Comment: Don't call methods from the same bean to start a new transaction. Call a method from **another** bean, injected into the first one.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet !