# Set isolation level in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I use Java, Spring Boot, CrudRepository and Postgresql.

How can set the isolation level in a CRUD Repo in Spring Boot or how can I set the isolation level in whole Spring Boot application.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) please. It works the same way in Boot and non-Boot Spring applications.

Answer (score 1):

Spring `creates proxies` for `all` the `classes` annotated with `@Transactional` – either on the `class or on any of the methods`. The proxy allows the framework to inject transactional logic before and after the method being invoked – mainly for starting and committing the transaction.

If the transactional bean is implementing an interface, by default the proxy will be a Java Dynamic Proxy. This means that only external method calls that come in through the proxy will be intercepted – any self-invocation calls will not start any transaction – even if the method is annotated with @Transactional.

---

Isolation:

`DEFAULT:` Use the default isolation level of the underlying database.

`Read Uncommitted:` Allows dirty reads

`Read Committed:` Does not allow dirty reads

`Repeatable Read:` If a row is read twice in the same transaction, the result will always be the same

`Serializable:` Performs all transactions in a sequence

### [image]

You should refer [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490852/spring-transactional-isolation-propagation) for more Details.

For Overview [Here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transaction-management) [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring) [Here](https://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-isolation-tutorial)