# Spring make an operation on a catch error of an Asynchronus Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, rollback

I've read the directives in the [Spring @Transactional - isolation, propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490852/spring-transactional-isolation-propagation)

but I don't understand how made this feature that I explain: I've an asynchronus method like this

```
@Transactional(timeout = TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Async("asyncImportExecutor")
public void startBeggin(Long id, String jwtToken) {

    try {
        . . .

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error: " + e);

        utilsService.setFlag(id, 0L); // every type of error, revert flag to 0
    }
```

and the utilService method called on catch, is this

```
 public void setFlag(Long id, Long state) {

    /* recover data from repository */
    Processo processo = getRepo().getOne(id);
    processo.setAvanzamento(state);
    getRepo().saveAndFlush(processo);
}
```

this method (setFlag) is called one time passing 1L before call the asynchronus method

```
getService().setFlag(id, (long) 1);
```

and at the end of all operations in asynchronus method passing zero

```
getService().setFlag(id, (long) 0);
```

but, if the asynchronus method fail for some problems, the call in the catch branch fail, because

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
```

and the flag remain to 1.

So, I hope I was clear, but ... how can I make sure that, on any exception that occurs between the operations within the asynchronous method (startBeggin)  after the rollback of that operations, set that value on that object?

How can I set (or update) a field on an object, on the roolback of a transaction (failed)?

The object impacted of the transactional method is the same (recovered by ID) but all the roolbacked operations don't are linked to that flag, that I want to set anyhow.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me a solution / idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach depends very much on what you want to accomplish here. But trying to give a simple answer:

> Transaction was marked for rollback only

means that all changes made database resources will be rolled back(not persisted) at the end of the transaction -> in your case at the end of your *startBeggin* method.

Thus, any database resources changed in `utilsService.setFlag` will also not be persisted -> beacasue the current transaction **is already marked** for rollback.

---

To avoid that, you need to have a new transaction **`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`** on `utilsService.setFlag` which will be isolated from the transaction created in *startBeggin* method.

You also should remember when @Transactional works:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations