# Spring @Transactional: interaction between isolation and propagation of transactions

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions, isolation-level

This directly relates to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8490852/9768291), as a natural follow-up question (which was asked in comments, but was never replied to).

## Textual description

Assuming:

- the application uses the default `REQUIRED` transactional propagation
- the application uses the `DEFAULT` transactional isolation
- the database's transactional isolation defaults to `READ_COMMITTED` (e.g. Postgres)

Two operations exist in separate classes:

1. Read some entries
2. Read some entries + Update them

Now assume that:

- the second operation calls the first one to fulfill the "Read some entries" part
- the second operation's method is marked with `@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)`
- the first operation's class is marked with `@Transactional`

**How does Spring behave in terms of managing transactions when calling the second operation?**

---

## Code description

```java
@Service
@Transactional
class Service1 {
  @Autowired MyRepo repo;

  void read(String id) {
    repo.findById(id);
  }
}

@Service
@Transactional
class Service2 {
  @Autowired Service1 readCommittedService;
  @Autowired MyRepo repo;

  @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
  void whatHappensNow(String id) {
    readCommittedService.read(id);
    repo.modifyRow(id);
  }
}
```

**What happens when we call `service2.whatHappensNow("foo")` ?**

Will Spring create a transaction, with `REPEATABLE_READ` isolation, and use that same isolation level when calling the repository via the `service1.read("foo")`?

And if a concurrent request is received, but this time it's a direct call to `service1.read("foo")` : will that transaction have the appropriate `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level, thus having no chance of failing or being blocked by that other request coming from `service2`?

Comment: It will use the transaction settings of the point where it started so `REPEATABLE_READ`. Unless you specify a different propagation level it might start a new transaction with a different isolation level. Each started transaction will have its own propagation and isolation level (as those are based on threads for storing the tx state, so each call will be properly set). I wonder why the question?

Comment: @M.Deinum your comment says "it **might** start a new transaction". That's precisely the ambiguity I'm trying to lift.

Comment: It won't start a new transaction **unless** there is also a `REQUIRES_NEW` else it won't. f