# Transactional Propagation in Spring Bott

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

How can i implement the below in Spring Boot.i need to calls 1st m1() and then m2()

m1 and m2 are 2 methods in 2 different classes which calls 2 different stored procedure .P_CODE is the ouput value retuned by m1 and m2 .

```
   begin
        m1()
        if p_code==0
        {
        m2()
        end transaction
        }
        else
        {
        end transaction
        begin
        m2()
        end transaction
        }
```

1. When p_code retuned by m1 is 0 then m1 and m2 should belong to same
   transaction.
2. When p_code retuned by m1 is not 0 then m1 and m2
   should belong to different transaction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring @Transactional - isolation, propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490852/spring-transactional-isolation-propagation)

Comment: @pringi Yes partly.