Spring Boot Concurrency/Multiple requests causing interleaving/corrupting data on stateful db table
Summary
Working on a Spring Boot backend which has an endpoint wired to a front end button. This endpoint does some refactoring of the inputs and then invokes two separate JPA repository methods. One updates records on the table, the second inserts a new record. It seems at times there are multiple requests hitting that endpoint and the methods are not being processed correctly. This could be from a user spamming the button, or multiple users making the same request. For debugging I was creating logs that generated unique UUID's and following each thread as they entered the endpoint, invoked the service, and subsequently invoked the repository methods. From what I can tell the updates and inserts are not being completed as a single action, and some interleaving is causing more updates to run before other updates instead of their "matching" insert.
Constraints

No access to the front end code
Cannot create stored procedure (DBA won't allow)

DB Table
This table is a long time already existing table, so I cannot modify it's design for the time being.
The way it is designed is it has a IS_LATEST column that basically keeps track of the most current state of an item, however when the application needs to update the state of that item, two things need to happen:

Update the existing IS_LATEST (current) record so that it's IS_LATEST value is FALSE, representing a past state of the item.
Insert a new record with all the new property values, with the latest property values and a IS_LATEST of TRUE

Code
Controller
    @Override
    @PostMapping("/updateMyDataTrackerLog/{dataLevel}/{targetMonth}/{screen}")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> updateCompletionStatus(@RequestBody final List<MyDataTrackerLogVo> request,
                                                             final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                                             @PathVariable(value = "dataLevel") final String dataLevel,
                                                             @PathVariable(value = "targetMonth") final String targetMonth,
                                                             @PathVariable(value = "screen") final Long screen) {
        try {
            final String userName = helper.getUserID(httpServletRequest);
            service.updateCompletionStatus(dataLevel, targetMonth, screen, request, userName);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseVO<>("Success"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseVO("Error"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

Service
    @Override
    public void updateCompletionStatus(final String dataLevel, final String targetMonth,
                                       final Long screen, final List<MyDataTrackerLogVo> request, String username) {
        String uuid = String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()); // used for logging, removed logs for brevity
        Map<String, Object> preparedInputsForUpdate = prepareMyDataTrackerLogForUpdate(dataLevel, targetMonth,
                screen, request, username, uuid);
        updateAndInsertMyDataTrackerLogs(preparedInputsForUpdate, uuid, username);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> prepareMyDataTrackerLogForUpdate(final String dataLevel, final String targetMonth,
                                                                 final Long screen,
                                                                 final List<MyDataTrackerLogVo> request,
                                                                 final String username, String uuid) {
        List<MyDataTrackerLog> batchedMyDataTrackerLogs = new ArrayList<>();
        final Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<>();
        if (request != null && !request.isEmpty()) {
            request.forEach(log -> {
                final MyDataTrackerLog myDataTrackerLog = DataSetTrackerMapper.INSTANCE.toDataSetTrackerToDomain(log);
                myDataTrackerLog.setLatest(true);
                // sets a bunch of properties
                batchedMyDataTrackerLogs.add(myDataTrackerLog);
            });

            List<String> possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings = request.stream()
                    .map(MyDataTrackerLogVo::getPossibleNestedCollectionOfStrings)
                    .collect(toList());
            inputs.put("possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings", possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings);
            inputs.put("myDataTrackerLogsBatch", batchedMyDataTrackerLogs);
        }
        return inputs;
    }

    protected void updateAndInsertMyDataTrackerLogs(Map<String, Object> inputs, String uuid, String username) {
        List<MyDataTrackerLog> batch = (List<MyDataTrackerLog>) inputs.get("myDataTrackerLogsBatch");
        List<String> possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings = (List<String>) inputs.get("possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings");
        MyDataTrackerLog logMetaData = batch.get(0);
         myDataTrackerLogRepository.updateIsLatestBatchedByPossibleNestedCollectionOfStrings(
                false,
                logMetaData.targetMonth(),
                logMetaData.dataLevel(),
                logMetaData.getScreenId(),
                possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings
        );
        myDataTrackerLogRepository.saveAll(batch);
    }

Repo Method for Updates
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("Update MyDataTrackerLog d SET "
            + "d.isLatest = :isLatest "
            + "where d.targetMonth = :targetMonth "
            + "AND d.level = :level AND d.screen = :screen "
            + "AND d.possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings in (:possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings) AND d.isLatest = true")
    void updateIsLatestBatchedByPossibleNestedCollectionOfStrings(
            final @Param("isLatest") Boolean isLatest, final @Param("targetMonth") Date targetMonth,
            final @Param("level") String level, final @Param("screen") Long screen,
            final @Param("possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings") List<String> possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings
    );

Notes

I've had to modify the code some for brevity as there is a lot more BL going on but irrelevant to this question.
The request's first level properties, will all be the same but there is a nested properties that can contain a list of values, for example:

requestOne

prop1
List of prop2 { 'justOneThing' }

requestTwo

prop 1
List of prop2 { '1', '2', '3' }

That second property is being batched and called using the IN SQL syntax to process them all at once instead of a loop (This was a previous suggestion to attempt to solve this concurrency issue)
Results
So Ideally the updates would wipe out any and all matching item records and set their IS_LATEST to false, immediately followed by an insert which would give the database the most current representation of the item record. Unfortunately I am seeing processing that occurs like this:
Same request from same user (button spamming scenario) :: Interleaving



Thread 1
Thread 2




Starts Update




Starts Update


Finish Update



Starts Insert




Finish Update



Starts Insert


Finish Insert




Finish Insert



What I believe is happening is the T2 finish update isn't catching the first insert, causing there to be two "current" item records.
Conclusion/Question
I suspect the solution here is to make the update and insert a single atomized action, and the only way I can think of doing this is to lock the table, but I've unsuccessfully tried to implement this manually, with annotations, and then through hibernate. I must be doing something wrong. Are there any other approaches to solving this concurrency issue from the server side of things?
Update/Attempts
Tried adding a pessemistic write lock annotation on the service call that includes the jpa method calls. Still observing interlacing.
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Transactional
@Override
protected void updateAndInsertMyDataTrackerLogs(Map<String, Object> inputs, String uuid, String username) { // this had to become a public method according to intellij
        List<MyDataTrackerLog> batch = (List<MyDataTrackerLog>) inputs.get("myDataTrackerLogsBatch");
        List<String> possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings = (List<String>) inputs.get("possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings");
        MyDataTrackerLog logMetaData = batch.get(0);
         myDataTrackerLogRepository.updateIsLatestBatchedByPossibleNestedCollectionOfStrings(
                false,
                logMetaData.getTargetMonth(),
                logMetaData.getDataLevel(),
                logMetaData.getScreen(),
                possibleNestedCollectionOfStrings
        );
        myDataTrackerLogRepository.saveAll(batch);
    }

And tried updating the annotations on my repo method for the update
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE my_data_tracker_table WITH (HOLDLOCK) SET "
            + "IS_LATEST = :isLatest "
            + "where TARGET_MONTH = :targetMonth "
            + "AND LOB = :dataLevel AND SCREEN_ID = :screenId "
            + "AND IS_LATEST = 0", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateIsLatestBatchedByPossibleNestedCollectionOfStrings(
            final @Param("isLatest") Boolean isLatest, final @Param("targetMonth") Date targetMonth,
            final @Param("dataLevel") String dataLevel, final @Param("screenId") Long screenId
    );


You're correct that you want to do this in one atomic transaction.  Concurrency is easy to get wrong, but the below approach will err on the side of caution.
Below are Transact-SQL statements, but you can do some of these steps w/ JPA annotations, jdbc calls, etc.
Thread 1

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT .. FROM T1 WHERE IS_LATEST = 1
UPDATE T1 SET IS_LATEST = 0
INSERT ....
COMMIT TRAN

SERIALIZABLE isolation mode causes the first SELECT to act as a mutex, blocking other rows till the transaction commits (or rolls back).
You can accomplish the same effect with query hints (UPLOCK, HOLDLOCK on the SELECT).  Using query hints has the benefit that you don't need to reset the isolation mode afterwards.  (JDBC connection pools don't always reset things to a clean slate between borrows and using SERIALIZABLE everywhere is probably NOT what you want).
Serializable isolation mode
Relevant question about UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK

Thanks, this makes sense. I'll give this implementation a try, and report back asap.

iirc, you'll have to use EntityManager for the transaction, not explicit BEGIN/COMMIT TRAN.  (I'm a DBA w/ a wee bit of Java/spring boot knowledge)

I was looking at these query hints, Is it possible to annotate, say a service method that has multiple repository method calls within it? Hopefully achieving a lock from method invocation until it receives/hears a commit?

You can use the @Transactional annotation to handle the BEGIN/COMMIT, but you'll need to add the query hints in your SQL. @Query(nativeQuery=true).

So convert the update query method to a nativeQuery, then add the hints to that same query? How would I go about adding the hints... something like this?
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE my_table_name WITH (HOLDLOCK) SET ...."
And do I need to annotate the saveAll() ie the second db op (INSERT)?

Going through the resources and advice provided by @StrayCatDBA I found a working solution:
TL;DR

Use the spring framework @Transactional annotation and set the isolation level to the highest setting: SERIALIZABLE

Expand the scope by placing the annotation high enough in the stack to fully atomize the repo methods


Explaination
The placement of the annotation, thus defining the scope of this transactional "lock" if you will was part of my solution as well. My code made use of a facade type service method called in the controller, which further called some service methods which organized/reformatted the request payload data before pass the data to the repository methods. My issue was I was placing too small of a scope, allowing multiple threads to being the series of repo method operations, whenever there was an open tick (sorry not much of a hardware person). Lifting the annotation to the facade service call in the controller method seems to have atomized the two repo method operations.
Code
// This method is called in the controller endpoint
@Override
// Add this annotation and isolation level.
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) 
public void updateCompletionStatus(final String dataLevel, final String targetMonth, final Long screen, final List<MyDataTrackerLogVo> request, String username) {
    String uuid = String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()); // used for logging, removed logs for brevity
    Map<String, Object> preparedInputsForUpdate = prepareMyDataTrackerLogForUpdate(dataLevel, targetMonth, screen, request, username, uuid);
    // originally I tried placing the transactional annotation on this method definition
    updateAndInsertMyDataTrackerLogs(preparedInputsForUpdate, uuid, username);
}

Further more there is another SO post that does a wonderful job of explaining what was happening and how the isolation levels can be leverage depending on your use case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490932/5094207
